# Firebase snapshot.data.documents with flutter: what exactly am I doing here?

Tags: firebase, flutter, snapshot

I would like to understand better how firebase works?

Let's say I have a firestore database and there is a collection ("books") and I have several documents containing different info like title, authors, url of the book image, publication date, etc. I want to present the information in a list. Here is my code

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('books')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final booksDB = snapshot.data.documents;
            List<Book> books = [];
            for (var rest in booksDB) {
              final restName = rest.data['name'];
              final restURL = rest.data['url'];

                final book = Book(
                  name: restName,
                  url: restURL,
                );
                books.add(book);
            }

            return ListView(
              children: books,
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class Book extends StatelessWidget {
  Book({this.name, this.url});

  final String name;
  final String url;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: url != null
                    ? url
                    : 'https://webhostingmedia.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/http-error-404-not-found.png',
                placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20) / 3 * 2,
                fit: BoxFit.cover),

        ),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 20.0,
            left: 20.0,
            child: Text(name,
                style: kSendButtonTextStyle.copyWith(
                  backgroundColor: kColorPrimary.withOpacity(0.5),
                ))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my question: what am I exactly doing when I am writing `final booksDB = snapshot.data.documents;`?
Am I downloading all the documents and all the related fields? Or am I just creating a reference? I would like to know if I am downloading all the info or just the one I am adding to the books list (name and url)

This is important to me because I would like to control my firebase reads and I do not need to read something if I am not using it...

I hope the question is clear. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a collection ("books") and I have several documents containing
>   different info like title, authors, url of the book image, publication
>   date, etc.

That will work but I think it is not the intended way. You see, a collection of books should contain several documents of books. One document holds all the information of one book. What you did is spreading one book data to multiple documents, this way you won't be able to add more than one book in the same collection. It should be like this:

```
_firestore.collection('books').document(bookID); //This accesses one book.
//The name of the document is the book id which you can specify manually or automatically, but it should be unique.
```

Then inside each document you can have multiple fields.

> Here is my question: what am I exactly doing when I am writing `final
>   booksDB = snapshot.data.documents;`? Am I downloading all the
>   documents and all the related fields? Or am I just creating a
>   reference? I would like to know if I am downloading all the info or
>   just the one I am adding to the books list (name and url)

Since you have the `snapshot` it means the documents are already downloaded inside the `snapshot` object. `booksDB` here is only a reference to the already downloaded documents.

Here is some useful references:

- Using Firestore as a backend to your Flutter app https://youtu.be/DqJ_KjFzL9I
- Get to know Cloud Firestore https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ

Comment: Thanks. To clarify: my book collection actually contains several document of books as you said. Each book document contain the fields I have mentioned

Comment: So when I create the constant booksDB I am actually download all the document in that collection including all the fields in the documents of that collection, correct?

Comment: When you create the final object `booksDB` you are creating a reference to an already downloaded documents.  The documents were downloaded before the creation of `booksDB` object. What I am trying to say is whether you created the `booksDB` object or not, all the documents inside `'books'` collection will be downloaded and referenced inside the object `snapshot`.

Comment: Understood. Can you point out where exactly in my code I am downloading the documents?

Comment: `StreamBuilder` is donwloading them in the background as long as you have this line: `stream: _firestore.collection('books').snapshots()` .

Comment: just another question.... does the streamBuilder download the data only once or many times?? for example if I setState does the streamBuilder download a new version of the data? I hope not...